# GitHub workflow restriction

Tags: github, github-actions

I have deployment action in my GitHub workflow.
I want to restrict this action trigger to the master branch only.

Here is a piece of workflow config:

```
on:
  release:
    branches:
      - master
    types:
      - released
```

But when I'm publishing pre-release for any branch in my project it hits workflow immediately.

What's wrong with it? Please advice.
Tnx!

Comment: Why not using the `published` or `prereleased` types instead of `released`? To resolve your problem, you could use an `if` condition to perform the operation only if the `github.ref` value from the [github.context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) is `refs/heads/master`.

Comment: @GuiFalourd thank you!
I just wonder maybe you know, why in my above example `branches` doesn't restrict workflow to the master branch only?

Comment: @GuiFalourd this solution (with if and refs/heads/master) doesn't work if I tag and publish into the master branch.

Is there way to restrict workflow step to specific tag and master branch ?

Comment: You could use a regex for tag values using something like`v*.*.*` ([reference](https://github.community/t/how-to-run-github-actions-workflow-only-for-new-tags/16075/10)). Now, you can't set 2 mandatory reasons as `ON` triggers. It will always be a `OR` statement. However, you can achieve what you want using a trigger AND an `if` condition, that's why I suggested it on the first comment.

Comment: @GuiFalourd but looks like `github.ref` doesn't contain info about branch when I published a tag, isn't it?

Comment: You can try using `github.context` to see what variables you can access in your workflow (I don't remember exactly which one are available with that trigger). To check the github context variables in your workflow, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68068674/8496462)