# Get commit SHA in Github actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In a Github action you can get the commit SHA using `${GITHUB_SHA}`, which is [a default env variable.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables). However, this commit SHA seems to be a merge commit!? which does not equal the commit SHA displayed on PR's Github UI. Any thoughts on how I can get the SHA that is displayed in PRs (on Github UI)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### To understand what happens

Reference: [Github community post](https://github.community/t/why-does-merge-commit-sha-change-during-action-run/129932) with the **weide-zhou (Github Partner)** answer.

> When you can create a pull request, github will execute workflow based
> on a fake merge branch: `refs/pull/:prNumber/merge`, the
> `merge_commit_sha` doesn’t exist on base or head branch, but points to
> that surrogate merge commit, and there is a mergeable key to show the
> status of the test commit.
>
> Therefore, here, the `github.sha` stands for the actual merge commit.

#### Github Variables

Tip: you can print the `GitHub variables` using the following step:

```
- name: Show GitHub context
  env:
    GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
  run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

It seems that what you want here is the `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}` value.

In the case of `pull_request`, the hash of the latest commit can be found in the `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}` variable, whereas `${{ github.sha }}` refers to the PR merge commit.

*Note that if the pull_request has been opened for a fork repo, the `github.event.pull_request` variable will be empty (don't know if it's a bug or something they are working on).*

Comment: Don't you know if there is a universal solution, whether the workflow is triggered from PR or merge commit to master?

Comment: I don't think there will be an universal solution as long as the github context json follows a different structure for bothe triggers.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to check whether it is a push to develop or pull request commit so we can do "if the PR, do this, if the push to a branch, do that"?

Comment: I don't know how to identify the difference currently, as a pull request commit **pushed** to a branch is considered a **push event** in GHA.

Answer (score 11):

It's not a direct answer to the question, but google suggested me this question when I was looking for a universal solution for getting SHA, whether it's `push` or `pull_request`, so my answer could be helpful for someone.

```yaml
- name: Setup Environment (PR)  
  if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}  
  shell: bash  
  run: |  
    echo "LAST_COMMIT_SHA=${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}  
- name: Setup Environment (Push)  
  if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}  
  shell: bash  
  run: |  
    echo "LAST_COMMIT_SHA=${GITHUB_SHA}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
```

So now we can use the `LAST_COMMIT_SHA` from the ENV to get the last commit SHA.
If we need it in multiple workflows, we can put these steps to a custom action

```yaml
# .github/actions/prepare/action.yml
name: 'Preparation'
description: ''
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Setup Environment (PR)  
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}  
      shell: bash  
      run: |  
        echo "LAST_COMMIT_SHA=${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}  
    - name: Setup Environment (Push)  
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}  
      shell: bash  
      run: |  
        echo "LAST_COMMIT_SHA=${GITHUB_SHA}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
```

and call it one of the first steps in each workflow

```yaml
# .github/workflows/ci.yml
# ...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Prepare
        uses: ./.github/actions/prepare
# ...
      - name: Set build tag
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "BUILD_TAG=${LAST_COMMIT_SHA:0:7}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted for Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to detect the pull request even and override the `GITHUB_SHA` with the correct one:

```
if [ "$GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" == "pull_request" ]; then
    GITHUB_SHA=$(cat $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH | jq -r .pull_request.head.sha)
fi
```

Reference: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26325