# Get commit hash that triggered the workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am planning to revert merged commit where approval from a specific group has not been obtained via Github Actions. How do we get the commit that triggered this workflow?

I am planning to use [filters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet)to check whether PRs containing changes to a specific file path was merged.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - main
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  my-action:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
    runs-on: ...
```

Would the following be sufficient to identify the specific commit to be reverted?

```
git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")
git_branch=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}
```

Comment: It seems sufficient to me (another thread about this topic for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061051/get-commit-sha-in-github-actions/68068674#68068674)

Comment: Thanks for linking the other thread @GuiFalourd Makes sense to me.